# Not able to access facebook posts details in which user got tagged by another person using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have registered a facebook application. By using that application we are trying to access the posts in which the user has got tagged.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/tagged

By using the above mentioned URL we are accessing the tagged posts of the user who has given the below mentioned permission's(we asked for almost all the permission's allowed by Facebook) to our application.

Our application has permission to read name, profile picture, friends list, timeline posts, status updates, photos details of the user after acquiring the user access token.

While accessing the api(https://graph.facebook.com/me/tagged), we are getting the below response all the time, even though the user has got tagged in multiple posts.

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

We are able to access the posts of the user which were created by him by using the following graph API

https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts

**Our Application is in Development Mode, It's not yet live**

Comment: Do both profiles, tagger and taggee(?), have a role in your app? Not sure if this is supposed to work in dev mode otherwise to begin with. Plus, the documentation explicitly mentions that you might simply not be able to get everything there is, _“Even with the user_posts permission, it is possible that your app may not be able to read all of a person's posts, or posts that a person is tagged in. Your app's ability to see a specific post must pass several privacy checks, including a person's platform privacy settings.”_

Comment: @04FS thanks for your reply. As you asked, taggee has a role in our application, which is an admin. but the tagger doesn't have a role in our application. As per the Graph API documentation, If the taggee has allowed the application to have all the above mentioned permissions then application should be able to access / read all the tagged posts details. Please correct me, if im wrong.

Comment: Yes, but since your app is still in dev mode, additional restrictions might apply.

Comment: @04FS but our application is mainly focused on this feature. So our app is in-complete. Is it possible to get approved by the facebook app review process at this stage? We are just getting started now. Are you suggesting that we shouldn't ask these permissions while starting the development or are there any steps we need to take to overcome this ?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you test this with a case where both users have a role in your app first.

Comment: @04FS, the problem here is we are not able to get the tagged posts. We are able to receive the normal posts of the user. If i add both users to my app, it'll notify me as the "User 1 has created a new post" not as "User 1 has tagged User2". In realtime the tagger wont know about the taggee's approved application and he wont register / install the app before tagging the taggee

Comment: @04FS our application is mainly trying to fetch the tagged posts of the user. So the user only need to install / provide access permissions to our application. Here the tagger doesn't need to know about the application itself.

Comment: Sorry, don’t know to which level this still is supposed to work. Facebook might have restricted this further, to enhance privacy. Maybe file a bug report asking for clarification, under which circumstances you can still expect to get such tagged posts via API.

Answer (score 0):

We have figured out the solution. If somebody has the similar problems in future, it will be useful for them

**Solution**

Since the application is in development mode, it can only able to access the data's of Admin's, Developer's, Tester's.

Even though the facebook has mentioned that "If the person who gets tagged by others give permission to the application, it can be able to access all the tagged posts". This statement is true when the application goes to live / production state.

But in development mode it's not the same case. After the cambridge analytica's hack / Exploiting security & privacy bug at facebook, they modified lot's of rules.

**If you want to access the tagged posts of an user both the person's(tagger / who tags the other person and the taggee / who gets tagged by the other person) has to have a role in the application and both the users have to install the application and have to provide necessary permissions**

We tested the above solution multiple times.

To Add a role, we have to follow the below steps:

**Pre-Setup:**

First register the normal user account as a developer account. Now the user can be added in any Roles in any Application.

**Add Role**

To add a role, we have to go to the application's developer dashboard. Then go to Roles -> Roles Section to add new user's as a Admin / Developer / Tester.

Then install the application in the user account, which is now a development account by using the OAuth2 Flow(you can use Javascript sdk provided by Facebook or you can implement any of the Facebook login's supported by Facebook)